# IntegrateJenkins to trigger ZAP without selenium

Tags: automated-tests, zap, automated-deploy

Is there a way to Integrate Jenkins after job build is completed to trigger Zed attack Proxy(Zap) without using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the official ZAP Jenkins add-on? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/zap+plugin